# Implementing ripple on MDC slider

Tags: slider, material-design, angular6, ripple

I'm working with MDC and trying to apply a ripple effect to my slider thumb. I followed the documentation and added the sass mixins, but the styles will only apply if I select the entire slider, not just the thumb. I've tried a number of different Sass combinations to select the thumb/container but none have worked. I also tried moving the styles to the global sass file instead of the component styles and that was also unsuccessful.

[MDC Documentation](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-ripple)

```css
//These styles apply 
.mdc-slider{
    @include mdc-ripple-surface;
    @include mdc-ripple-radius-unbounded(100%);
    @include mdc-states($action-blue, true);
    @include mdc-states-base-color($action-blue);
    @include mdc-states-hover-opacity(.1);
    @include mdc-states-focus-opacity(.26);
    @include mdc-states-press-opacity(.26);
}

//These do not
.mdc-slider__thumb{
    @include mdc-ripple-surface;
    @include mdc-ripple-radius-unbounded(100%);
    @include mdc-states($action-blue, true);
    @include mdc-states-base-color($action-blue);
    @include mdc-states-hover-opacity(.1);
    @include mdc-states-focus-opacity(.26);
    @include mdc-states-press-opacity(.26);
}

.mdc-slider__thumb-container{
    @include mdc-ripple-surface;
    @include mdc-ripple-radius-unbounded(100%);
    @include mdc-states($action-blue, true);
    @include mdc-states-base-color($action-blue);
    @include mdc-states-hover-opacity(.1);
    @include mdc-states-focus-opacity(.26);
    @include mdc-states-press-opacity(.26);   
}
```

```html
<mdc-slider min="0" max="50" value="35"></mdc-slider>
```

Comment: Please could you link to the documentation that you followed so that any others can more easily see how you got to where you are now, which in turn will enable better more informed answers. Thanks

Comment: @Damo added below my summary